# Simplify List of coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have suplied a template image and a test image to the function `cv.matchTemplate`.

After returning, I filter anything out under 95% match. The results are good and I am producing the desired result. The result is a list of tuples each tuple represented by `(x,y)` The problem is after filtering I have too many results. It seems that each potential match yields more than one point:

```
(150, 143)
(151, 143)
(152, 143)
(153, 143)
(154, 143)
(155, 143)
(149, 144)
(150, 144)
(151, 144)
(152, 144)
(153, 144)
(154, 144)
(155, 144)
(156, 144)

(694, 144)
(695, 144)
(696, 144)
(697, 144)
(698, 144)

(148, 145)
(149, 145)
(150, 145)
(151, 145)
(152, 145)
(153, 145)
(154, 145)
(155, 145)
(156, 145)
(157, 145)

(692, 145)
(693, 145)
(694, 145)
(695, 145)
(696, 145)
(697, 145)
(698, 145)
(699, 145)

(147, 146)
(148, 146)
(149, 146)
(150, 146)
(151, 146)
(152, 146)
(153, 146)
(154, 146)
(155, 146)
(156, 146)
(157, 146)
```

All of these points are `tuples` that are in a single sorted `list` You can see the points can be "logically" grouped together in bunches that are not too different in their coordinates. In the above example output, there are 5 distinguishable "groups". The idea here is to *reduce* each **group** into **one point**

from above, this would be condensed to the following list:

```
(151,143)
(694, 144)
(148, 145)
(692, 145)
(147, 146)
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Could you explain how you simplified the grouped tuples together to form each single point?

Comment: If you imagine the points on a plot, you will notice that there are groups that are really close together. I basically want to simplify those points into one point. Currently I have no method of doing this, I am just explaining my desired result.

Comment: For each grouped tuple you can average the points to obtain a resulting point. In your output tuple list im not sure why you have two `(148, 145)` points

Comment: sorry I removed that, that was a typo. As for your suggestion, the tuples are not grouped, so the answer would require a way to group them.

Comment: i tried plotting and determined that the grouping is pretty subjective...you'll need to codify your rules if you want a tight solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this answer due to OP comment about all of the tuples being in a list.
The first if condition if something you can change if you find that you want to be more/less strict for differences between points (e.g. if you want it to be within 5 pixels, you can do <= 5 rather than == 1).

```
masterTest = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 8)] #test array
arrayHolder = [] #buffer that holds the first mini list
compositeArray = [] #master list which holds a list of the tuples, grouped
lastTuple = masterTest[0] #dummy variable
arrayHolder.append(masterTest[0]) # add the first one so we have something to compare to
masterTest.pop(0) # it's already in our data, don't want a dup
for tuples in masterTest:
    if (((abs(tuples[0] - lastTuple[0]) == 1 and abs(tuples[1] - lastTuple[1]) == 0)) or
         (abs(tuples[1] - lastTuple[1]) == 1 and abs(tuples[0] - lastTuple[0]) == 0)):
        arrayHolder.append(tuples)
    else:
        compositeArray.append(arrayHolder.copy()) #add buffer to master list 
        arrayHolder = [] #clear out the buffer
        arrayHolder.append(tuples) #restart a new buffer
    lastTuple = tuples # update last coordinate checked


compositeArray.append(arrayHolder) #clears the buffer one last time

pointArray = []
for lists in compositeArray:
    count = 0
    xavg = sum([x[0] for x in lists])/len(lists)
    yavg = sum([x[1] for x in lists])/len(lists)
    pointArray.append(tuple((xavg, yavg)))

print (pointArray)
```

You can use pythons round() function (its that simple, numberToRound.round()) if you want to do that.

Comment: "All of these points tuples are in a sorted list". There is only one list of tuples so your example would yield one x and one y. Using an average is ok but how can I separate these points into buckets before taking the average?.

Comment: edited to account for that. Change the if condition as you find necessary to differentiate between two different groups of points. If you are asking for some function to tell if the two points are in the same group beyond looking at the coordinates, that's over my head

Comment: I upvoted this because of the good attempt and solves the problem using a few conditions. I discovered something called K means clustering. I think I will attempt this algorithm instead as it is more unassuming.

Comment: Actually the K means clustering without specified K is way more costly.

Comment: Ah ok. I misinterpreted the question a bit. Best of luck- if you don't mind posting your implementation after you finish that would be neat and helpful to others looking in the future

Comment: What I mean to say is I initially thought k-means clustering would help this, but it actually doesn't fix the problem I'm having